# How do I get POST data in circuits (Python)?

Tags: python, post, python-3.5, circuits-framework

I instantiate and register WebManager as part of my app.  I'm running a workflow and web app together.  Everything works find, except for getting POST data.

```
class WebSite(Controller):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

    def detail(self, id):
        return "Web ID: {}".format(id)


class WebService(Controller):

    channel = "/WebService"

    def POST(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(args) + ' ' + str(kwargs) + ' ' + 'Why are these empty?'


class WebManager(Component):
    def init(self):
        Server(('0.0.0.0', 80)).register(self)
        WebSite(self).register(self)
        WebService(self).register(self)
```

Using the following to call:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost')
print(r.text)
# Output: Hello World!

r = requests.get('http://localhost/detail?id=12')
print(r.text)
# Output: Web ID: 12

r = requests.post('http://localhost/WebService', json={'bob': 1, 'joe': {'blue': 43}})
print(r.text)
# Output: () {} Why are these empty?
```

I been through the docs and can't figure out how I get the body data of the post.  I assumed it would be passed in as one of the arguments.  I've also stopped in PyCharm debugger and looked through the self object of WebService and see nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it always that you find the answer just after you ask the question?

When the POST method executes, there is a .request.body property of the Controller.  This is an io.BytesIO object, so read like a file and gets bytes sent in.

```
class WebService(Controller):

    channel = "/WebService"

    def POST(self):
        # I'm using JSON, so decoding the bytes to UTF-8 string to load
        data = json.loads(self.request.body.read().decode('UTF-8'))
        return 'Data: {}'.format(data)
```